# Node js using data returned from request/request api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, httprequest

I am making a node api call using npm request

Here is some basic sample code

```
request = require('request');

ApiRequest = function (options) {
    this.uri = 'http://sampleapi.com/' + options.path,
    this.method = options.method,
    this.json = options.json
};

ApiRequest.prototype.call = function () {
    request(this, function (error, response, body) {
        if (body) {
            console.log(body);
        } else {
            console.log(error || "There was a problem placing your request")
        }
    });
};

exports.startApiCall = function () {
    options = {
        path: 'available',
        method: 'GET'
    };
    var myRequest = new Request(options);
    myRequest.call();
};
```

When I call the call() on the ApiRequest prototype the only think I seem to be able to do is something like console log the output, I am sure if I was using a data base I would be able to insert it. I want the call function to return me an object of the results to where it was called from ( exports.startApiCall ) so I can re use the function as sometimes I want to console log it and sometimes use it to build up a different call.

I have tried to return the body from the request, returning the request its self gives me a huge object with no body. I also tried to set the body to a variable and return it at the bottom of the function. How ever noting seems to be working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to create an asynchronous interface using callback functions  that can notify the caller when the operation is done and what the result is.  You can use plain callbacks or promises.

Comment: You are hiding the request variable in your startApiCall... Rename it to something else - `var r = new Request(options)`

Comment: I tried to make it a callback but I did not seem to be able to return it as it just returned the value of request which has nothing to do with the body. How would I implement promises @jfriend00 ?

Comment: I will sort out the confusing variable names now @lujcon thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have variable name conflicts. Rename your local request variable to something else. Ex:

```
request = require('request');

Request = function (options) {
    this.uri = 'http://sampleapi.com/' + options.path,
    this.method = options.method,
    this.json = options.json
};

Request.prototype.call = function (callback) {
    request(this, function (error, response, body) {
        if (body) {
            callback(error, body)
        } else {
            console.log(error || "There was a problem placing your request");
            callback(error);
        }
    });
};

exports.startApiCall = function (callback) {
    options = {
        path: 'available',
        method: 'GET'
    };
    var myRequest = new Request(options);
    myRequest.call(function(error, body) {
       //check the error and body here;
       //do the logic
       //you can also pass it through to the caller
       callback && callback(error, body);
    });
};
```

When you consume your module (lets name it `mymodule`) you can do:

```
var my = require('mymodule');
my.startApiCall(function(error, body){
    //do something with body
});
```

If you don't want the consumer to play with errors and/or body directly you can remove the callback parameter:

```
exports.startApiCall = function () {
    options = {
        path: 'available',
        method: 'GET'
    };
    var myRequest = new Request(options);
    myRequest.call(function(error, body) {
       //check the error and body here;
       //do the logic
       //you can also pass it through to the caller
    });
};
```

Comment: I think the main point of the question is how to get the results from the request out of the api call function which you don't address.

Comment: Yes, I made a little mistake because i renamed the variables to make them a little more generic as they were very specific with what the call was about.

Comment: do you like this pattern? If not - I can provide you with promise based solution.

Comment: @lujcon What did you do there with passing the callback into the function? I need any solution to get the result of body back into my exports.startApiCall function so I can use it. All solutions that will do that are welcome and greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks! I will try What is the callback which is being passed into exports.startApiCall?

Comment: it's a function someone who will use your module can specify. If you don't want to expose the error and/or body to the caller you can remove it (it's optional)

Comment: Nice, I still seem to have it stuck in a call back how ever! I just want to use it now when I get back into my exports.StartApiCall for example I want this to be set to var result and then bellow the myRequest.call() use the variable result

Comment: You can't do that. All operations in nodejs are asynchronous so will end in the future. When your `call()` function ends you don't have body yet. The concept of nodejs is to use callbacks and preform actions inside callbacks.